# Trying to get property of non-object in CheckActivation

Tags: magento2

I have install via composer module disable debug log file.
https://marketplace.magento.com/maharyta-disable-debug.html

```
composer require maharyta/disable-debug:1.0.0
```

During update database:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

get error:

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/b2b/domains/style.pl/public_html/ven
  dor/maharyta/disable-debug/Helper/CheckActivation.php on line 62
```

CheckActivation.php on line 62:

```
/**
 * Check the activation key for the extension
 *
 * @throws Exception
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkActivationKey()
{
    if (!file_exists($this->_reader->getModuleDir('', 'Magexsto_DisableDebug') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'key.txt')) {
        throw new Exception("\r Install the activation key, please.");
    }
    $checkKeyResponse = $this->_sendCheckKeyRequest(
        file_get_contents($this->_reader->getModuleDir('', 'Magexsto_DisableDebug') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'key.txt')
    );
    if($checkKeyResponse->success !== true) {
        if(isset($checkKeyResponse->error_message)) {
            throw new Exception("\r" . $checkKeyResponse->error_message);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("\rYou have some problem with activation key");
        }
    }
   return true;
}
```

How to activate extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
/**
 * Check the activation key for the extension
 *
 * @throws Exception
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkActivationKey()
{
   // Remove broken code.
   return true;
}
```

---

Where the issue is likely:

`if($checkKeyResponse->success !== true) {`

How could someone write `$checkKeyResponse->success` where the property is blindly accessed, but then checking for existence when writing the very next line?  I mean, `isset($checkKeyResponse->error_message)` is first checking for the existence of the property...

Just use my first solution.

---

The developer has poorly written this code.  There should be members initialized or at least accessed via public method that would properly handle default values for whatever class variables are protected/private and being accessed.